# What should you do with a question when the answer becomes unverifiable?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, etiquette

[Custom SharePoint Designer 2007 Workflow Activity Works on Test Server, but not production](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24699/custom-sharepoint-designer-2007-workflow-activity-works-on-test-server-but-not)

Now that a business decision is forbidding me to test the above answer in our environment for correctness (and I have no interest in getting fired to determine the correct answer); and I'll never really be able to duplicate in another environment properly, am I expected to mark as the answer anyways? Or just close the question outright.  Thoughts?

Comment: you could always spawn a demo environment and test it out. You can use vendors like CloudShare.com (I have no affiliation to them, but like what they do) to create a SharePoint environment and test it out without risk for your own environment :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you really have both options in your post. I could make an argument either way I guess.

We should keep it open if we think it will help someone in the future. Alternatively, we should close it as "Too Localized" if we think this situation is too narrow to help people in the future.

At this point I would lean towards closing the question because it seems it is environment specific (works on test, but not in prod?).

Comment: Sounds good, I put in a vote to close on the question, feel free to deal as such, any of the potential answers COULD be helpful to the problem for someone else someday, so deleting outright may be a bad idea.

Comment: I went ahead and closed the question for you. :)